# Verifying powdered milk

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

If someone keeps cholov Yisroel but is lenient when it comes to powdered milk, is there a halachically reliable/valid way to verify that a product is made with powdered milk as opposed to fresh milk, other than calling the kosher certification for every product?

Comment: Your question is: is there a way to discern something aside from checking it? What other ways could there possibly be?

Comment: The package ingredients usually indicate the use of powdered milk. What is sometimes vague is the use of "lactose". Many years ago, Dr. Pepper used lactose that was actually dairy, and it had a "dairy" hechsher marking (I think it was OU certified at the time.) So, you may want to extend your concern to "chalav Yisra'el lactose", if it's still a concern. Not sure if it still is, or is all lactose now "artificial" or non-dairy?

Comment: @DoubleAA mesiach lfi tumo of the company maybe?

Comment: @DoubleAA some terminology in use in the ingredient list? (Which may be what YEZ meant.)

Comment: You can probably check in a lab.